# Drones and Integrals Project

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

Hello everyone and thanks for taking the time to read this post. So in my college calculus class we had the opportunity to fly a drone and get it's flight data. I have a spreadsheet featuring two columns (one is $x$-velocity and the other is time). I have graphed a velocity versus time graph given these points and I have also fitted a 6th degree polynomial trend line. I am trying to find the total displacement and the total distance that my drone flew.

So I know that a velocity-v-time graph provides several important things about the drone. The area underneath the curve is the total displacement of the drone; the slope of the graph is the drone's acceleration. In order to find the total displacement of the graph I have to use a definite integral. After getting my trend line equation, I tried to use a definite integral, but received a displacement way to high to be correct. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Some things to note: I have the actual displacement which was measured with measuring tape. The actual/theoretical displacement of my drone is $58\, cm$. When I graphed the trend line, my minimum $x$-point was $9.8$ because the drone started recording data even when it hovered and our professor said it was fine if we do not include that data. My maximum $x$-point is $18.7$ because this is when the drone completed its flight path and landed. Velocity was negative at some points during this flight. The equation I am supposed to use is as follows:

$$\int_9^T v(t)dt$$

I started off by making a graph of the velocity versus time and fitted a trend line for it. The equation for the trend line was: 
$$y = 1.3264x^6-116.14x^5+4179.3x^4-79079x^3+829395x^2-5000000x+10000000$$

After I integrated this equation for the time interval $[9.8, 18.7]$ I got a final answer of $-57519039.94$. This is obviously way wrong and I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

When performing numerical integration, about the **worst** thing you can do is fit to a high-order polynomial and then integrate that polynomial.  That approach is horribly sensitive to tiny fluctuations in the data, which means that with real data it often gives a nonsensical integral -- as you have seen in your case.

A reasonable (though hardly optimal) approach would be to divide your time interval into $n$ equal sub-intervals such that each sub-interval has at least about $n$ data points, then do a linear fit in each sub-interval, and add the areas of those trapezoids.  For your physics course, this will be more than adequate.

Estimation of an integral given noisy data is a highly non-trivial problem if you want to to it optimally.  On the other hand, the problem you pose is closely related to the problem of inertial guidance, so there is a huge body of work studying it.  But in your course, you really don't want to have to understand Kalman filters and the like!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There were actually two ways that I approached this project. I first used Reimann sums to calculate the displacement and got 77cm instead of the actual 58cm (which is understandable). The other way I was asked to approach this project was by using the equation I have provided above. I know that there were other ways to find the net area under the graph, but I wanted to see if I could do it the way I was asked to by using integrals. I have decided to switch my regression line to a fourth degree as well, taking what you said into account. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have used a fourth degree regression polynomial and that seems to have solved the problem. Thank you for your help.